# React invariant violation => inconsistent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this JSX in a React component's render function

```
 <footer className="footer">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2"><p className="text-muted">(Baymax team)</p></div>
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <div id="env-id">ENV: {appState.get('env')}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <div id="collection-div-id">
                    Collection: {window.currentCollection} // << this causes errors
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <div id="model-div-id">
                    Model: {window.currentModel}  //<< this doesn't cause errors
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <progress id="hot-reload-progress-bar" value="100" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

the error I get is

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_events, length, models, _byId, dispatchToken, uniqueName, givenName, options, collNeedsPersisting, numberOfFetches}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
```

Why does React thing I am trying to render a child component? And why does the error only happen for the Collection line and not the Model line (I take out the Collection line and the Model line does not throw).

Comment: It would help if we knew what `window.currentCollection` is. Array? Object? Other? Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(window.currentCollection, null, 2))` and copy/paste the result into your question.

Comment: *"Why does React thing I am trying to render a child component?"* Because you are passing the value of `window.currentCollection` as child to the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

JSX is unable to interpolate object literals using the `{[...]}` syntax, which means if we have an object named `baz` that equals `{foo: 'bar'}`, we won't be able to display the object with just `{baz}`, we can only peer into it via `{baz.foo}`.

In the provided example, we can see that `window.currentCollection` contains the following properties:

> found: object with keys {_events, length, models, _byId,
>   dispatchToken, uniqueName, givenName, options, collNeedsPersisting,
>   numberOfFetches

I suspect if you update the expression to read `{window.currentCollection.uniqueName}`, the component will render appropriately.

**Baz Example**

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/ZWLBqK?editors=0011

Comment: I see, it can only render strings, I thought it was trying to render it as a child component

Comment: Actually it's not quite accurate to say it can only render strings. React can render all kinds of things, but lux is right: not object literals or arrays.

Comment: @ffxsam +1. Agreed, and oddly enough it also doesn't render booleans; ternary to the rescue, but woof!

Comment: @Alex: This is what React can render: *"Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types."* https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html . Anything that you put inside a tag is a child, just like with DOM. Given `<div>{foo}</div>`, the value of `foo` is rendered as a child of the `<div>`.